# GreenDroid library , set drawable title in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, greendroid

Regarding GreenDroid library https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid:

1. I want to set a logo as title in the Action Bar. I've tried a couple of methods but with no result. How should I proceed?
2. When creating a GDApplication file, and set as *getHomeActivity* my main activity class, inside that activity my normal ActionBar title disappears, why and how could I bring it back ?

Comment: I solved my problems like this: I used the setType method for the ActionBar and I set it to ActionBar.Type.Empty and then only call the setTitle method for setting a custom title.

Comment: @AndreiCatinean write your comment as an answer :)

Comment: Such an old question :) Thanks @ataulm for reminding me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problems like this: I used the `setType` method for the ActionBar and I set it to `ActionBar.Type.Empty` and then only call the `setTitle` method for setting a custom title.